# Convert Mysql query to Mongodb find()

Tags: mysql, mongodb

I have a mongodb collection structured like this:

```
{ "client" : "CLIENTIDHERE", "amount" : 90, "invoice": "SOMEIDHERE", "date" : ISODate("2014-07-09T11:13:49.273Z") }
```

And need to select somehow all the payments made from a client. 
In mysql I would do something like this, but with mongodb I have really no clue.

```
SELECT SUM(amount) payments,client FROM invoices GROUP BY client;
```

What I tried:

```
db.invoices.find({
    $group: { 
        amount: {$sum: "$amount"}
    }
}, {
    $project:{ 
        amount: "$amount",
        client: "$client"
    }
})
```

But it didn't work. What did I do wrong?

EDIT: I get the following error:
error: { "$err" : "Unsupported projection option: amount", "code" : 13097 }

Comment: I was able to answer this question, but in your next one, please don't just write "it didn't work". It is much easier to help you when you describe the error accurately (what results do you expect, what results do you get instead).

Comment: I am sorry. I wrote the error in the comment.

Comment: Please write the error in your question so others can see it more easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your [$group](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) step doesn't define what to `GROUP BY`. MongoDB's equivalent for the SQL `GROUP BY` is the `_id` field of the $group statement which is missing from your query. Also, when you want to use [aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/), you need to use `.aggregate(` instead of `.find(`.

```
db.invoices.aggregate({
    $group: { 
        _id: "$client",
        amount: { $sum: "$amount"}
    }
});
```

This will write the client into the `_id` field. When you would rather want to have the field named `client`, you can fix that in the `$project` step, but otherwise the projection is not required in this case.

Comment: Could you possibly even mention to use `.aggregate()` instead of `.find()`. Probably 50% of an actual answer. No I'll n=make it 80% since it really is the important thing.

Comment: Somehow it doesn't work. I get the following error: 
error: { "$err" : "Unsupported projection option: amount", "code" : 13097 }

Comment: @NeilLunn how do I do that?

Comment: @NeilLunn OK, missed that.

Comment: @user3807877 You used `find` instead of `aggregate`. I updated my answer.